# How can we write text into the WPF Combo Box?

Tags: wpf

I have a requirement in WPF.

I windows forms, for the ComboBox control, there is a property call `DropDownStyle` which

has 3 states viz. `Normal, Dropdown(default) and Dropdownlist`

When the state is the default one(i.e. Dropdown), the user can type into that.

How to do the same stuff in the WPF combo box?.

Kindly help

Answer (score 17):

'ComboBox' has an attribute 'IsEditable', setting the value of this to true will allow the user to enter text.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" />
```

Comment: Thanks .. I posted the same before I look into ur's solution. But thanks a lot